# List based dropdown menu not working in IE

Tags: html, css, wordpress, internet-explorer, web

I'm working on this website: http://cecraig.hhdev.hothousemarketing.com

The dropdown menus are not working properly in IE (I've tested in IE9 and IE8).  The child menu (ul) only appears when hovering over the text of the parent, as soon as the mouse goes outside the text it disappears.  I've used the same method for dropdown menus on other sites and it works fine in IE, not sure why it isn't working here.  I know IE has had limited support for :hover on elements other than "a", but from what I can find out that was only up to IE7.

Here is the CSS I am using for the menu, you can bring up the source to the see the HTML for the menu (which is outputted by the wp_nav_menu() WordPress function):

```
#mainNav ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
}
#mainNav > ul {
margin-left: 234px;
height: 38px;
}
#mainNav > ul > li {
position: relative;
float: left;
}
#mainNav ul li a {
font-size: 11pt;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
}
#mainNav > ul > li > a {
display: block;
height: 18px;
padding: 10px 12px;
}
#mainNav ul li a:hover {
color: #efefef;
}
#mainNav ul li.current-menu-item > a, #mainNav > ul > li.current-page-parent > a {
font-weight: bold;
}
#mainNav ul ul {
background-color: #e1a100;
display: none;
margin: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 38px;
left: 0;
width: 200px;
padding: 0 8px 8px 8px;
z-index: 99999;
}
#mainNav ul li:hover > ul {
display: block;
}
#mainNav ul ul li + li {
margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
.menu-item:hover{ display: block; }
```

IE doesn't do so well with complex hover selectors.

Comment: it's not the .menu-item I want to turn into a block on hover though, it's the child ul.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem with `:hover` you should use it on `<a>` elements. Because IE supports the `:hover` only on the `<a>` tags, but not on `li,div,span,dd,etc...`